# Get all OWLAnonymousClassExpressions via OWL-API

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

Using OWLAPI Version 3.5.0.

Is it possible to get all OWLAnonymousClassExpressions within an ontology?
Or even the OWLAnonymousClassExpressions that belong to a single OWLClass?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by belonging to an owl class?

Comment: E.G.: The class Parent has two superclasses; the named class Person and the anonymous restriction. I want to get the anonymous restriction/OWLAnonymousClassExpression

Comment: Can you check if the answer below satisfies your question, and accept it if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the direct, asserted superclasses for the named class from an OWLOntology object by calling the  [getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4_1_0/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAxiomIndex.html#getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass-) method.

This will return axioms with both kinds of superclass - anonymous *and* western, err, I  mean named. If you iterate over the result, you can select the anonymous class expressions using the isAnonymous method. 
If you  need indirect superclasses, you can recursively fetch the subclass axioms for any  named classes.

Depending on your requirements, you may also want to check  equivalent class axioms, since every equivalent class expression in an axiom is a superclass of all the others. These can be retrieved using the [getEquivalentClassesAxioms](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4_1_0/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAxiomIndex.html#getEquivalentClassesAxioms-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass-) method.

If you do follow parent links, or expand equivalences, you may need to keep track of the named classes you have already processed in case there are cycles.

If you want to include inferred superclasses as well as directly asserted ones, you can create a reasoner and use that to find the named superclasses of your chosen class. You can then retrieve the anonymous superclasses by fetching the subclass axioms as described above.

Let me know if this makes sense, or if sample code would be useful.

Edit: `OWLClassExpressionCollector` could also be useful, as it collects all class expressions from any `OWLObject`: ontology, axiom, or expression.